# Unable to add "nodes" in shader editor

Tags: materials, node-editor, interface, shaders

I'm not able to add any nodes in shader editor. When I'm pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> only "search" appears. I'm aware of turning on the "use nodes" but it's also not there in my material properties. What's the problem?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the same empty list if you pick add from the toolbar? Also, what version of blender are you using?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same situation. My version of blender is 2.82.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know, that's strange, I can't even seem to find any info on similar problems. Maybe try closing blender and restarting from the command line and adding `--debug-all --factory-startup`. If it gives you a log file, look for anything strange, and see if the nodes are working.

Comment: Okay. Will try that. Thank you

Comment: I did as you suggested. One problem is fixed because now i have "use nodes" available under the surface tab, but im still not able to add any nodes. Nothing appears there

Comment: Do you have any add-ons enabled? It could be that one of them is misbehaving and breaking things. Disable all add-ons and then restart Blender without them and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I have tried that already. Still the same situation

Comment: Still strange. Anything seem off in the log? Maybe it's just best to try a fresh copy. Just curious, are you using the steam version by any chance?

Comment: No I'm using version from official website. I will try reinstalling blender then. Thank you all for help